# How can you make a ghost block in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I forgot how to summon falling blocks, and all the videos were not helping. I'm not very good with the commands which involve using [, so if I could get an answer, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~ ~ {Time:1,BlockState:{Name:cobblestone_stairs}}
```

This is will summon a falling block, in this case a cobblestone_stair. Each of the `~` represent the x y and z coordinates.